# Is it possible to access the packet when using bpf_loop?

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

I have tried a number of ways to access the packet when using bpf_loop with XDP.  However verification always fails.

The following is an example of a program that I thought should pass verification but does not.  It will fail verification reporting:
invalid access to packet, off=0 size=1, R2(id=2,off=0,r=0)
R2 offset is outside of the packet

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

typedef struct context {
    struct xdp_md *ctx;
} context_t;

static int do_check(__u32 index, context_t *search_ctx)
{
    __u8 *data = (__u8 *)(long)search_ctx->ctx->data;
    __u8 *data_end = (__u8 *)(long)search_ctx->ctx->data_end;
    __u8 *this_byte;

    if (index > 0 && index <= 100)
    {        
        this_byte = data + index;

        // When run with this change it will pass verification
        //this_byte = data + 100;
        
        if (this_byte >= data && this_byte < data_end) 
        {
            if (*this_byte == 123)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

SEC("filter")
int  xdp_parser_func(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    context_t search_ctx = (context_t) 
    { 
        .ctx = ctx
    };
    
    bpf_loop(1, do_check, &search_ctx, 0);
    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Interestingly one can access the packet at a hard coded location.  The above will work if the  commented out line is put back in.

Is there something about how the verifier works with bpf_loop that means it will never allow access to the packet at a calculated location?  Or am I simply missing a check to convince the verifier that it is safe?

If it's important my Kernel version is 6.5.0-17-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things with the code above that the verifier trips over.

The verifier has a condition that asserts that the maximum possible value of a packet pointer can be 0xFFFF (max value of a unsigned 16-bit int). But since `index` is a u32 and we add it to `data` we exceed this max value. The verifier isn't smart enough in this case to recognize the `index <= 100` in the if. So what we can do instead is to do a binary AND with 0x7FFF (`index = index & 0x7FFF;`). This doesn't change anything practically, execpt that the verifier can now be certain that `index` is never bigger than 0x7FFF which is smaller than 0xFFFF.

The second catch is simpler, when bounds checking to see if you can access a given value we have to account for the size we want to access. So instead of `this_byte < data_end` we need to go `this_byte + 1 < data_end`. If you were to access a u16 you would have to make sure that 2 bytes are available `this_u16 + 2 < data_end`.

Those two combined allow the program to pass, at least for me locally (v6.5):

```c
static int do_check(__u32 index, context_t *search_ctx)
{
    __u8 *data = (__u8 *)(long)search_ctx->ctx->data;
    __u8 *data_end = (__u8 *)(long)search_ctx->ctx->data_end;
    __u8 *this_byte;

    index = index & 0x7FFF;
    if (index > 0 && index <= 100)
    {
        this_byte = data + index;

        // When run with this change it will pass verification
        // this_byte = data + 100;

        if (this_byte >= data && this_byte + 1 < data_end)
        {
            if (*this_byte == 123)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```